# Retrieving images from MySQL Database - file path

Tags: php, mysql

I've got my query working, it brings me the results I expect, but one column is going to be images, and I'm unsure of the best way to go about displaying them.

Initially I used the below code to get my results, without worrying about the images.

```
<?php

#requires connect script - similar to include to avoid including security details
require 'connectscript.php';

#query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE CategoryName = 'Surfboards'";
#result
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or die ("Bad Query: $sql");

#Opening table
#while loop to bring all results
echo "<table border='2'>";
echo "<tr><td>ProductID</td><td>Name</td><td>Brand</td><td>Model</td>
<td>Board Length</td><td>Board Type</td><td>Colour</td><td>Image</td>
<td>UnitPrice</td></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<tr>
            <td>{$row['ProductID']}</td>
            <td>{$row['Name']}</td>
            <td>{$row['Brand']}</td>
            <td>{$row['Model']}</td>
            <td>{$row['BoardLength']}</td>
            <td>{$row['BoardType']}</td>
            <td>{$row['Colour']}</td>
            <td style='width:200px; height: 100px; overflow-hidden;'>{$row['Image']}</td>
            <td>{$row['UnitPrice']}</td>
        </tr>";

}
echo"</table>"

?>
```

I've also adjusted the code slightly with an img src in there, and it presents the broken as if it's looking for an image, but can't find one.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['ProductID']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['Name']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['Brand']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['Model']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['BoardLength']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['BoardType']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['Colour']}</td>";
    echo "<td style='width: 400px; height: 400px; overflow-hidden;'><img 
    src=images/{$row['Image']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['UnitPrice']}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo"</table>"

?>
```

The images are stored in an images folder, within the htdocs folder on my xampp installation. I've double checked the path. The data type us VARCHAR and i've tried with and without the extention.

Any Suggestions?

Thanks

Will

Comment: What are you getting and what you want to do?

Comment: check the output of `$row['Image']` from element tab of browser

Comment: So what is stored in the `Images` column? Is it spelt correctly? Is it `Images` or `images`?

Comment: The filename and extension. The folder they're stored in is called images.

Comment: <td style='width: 400px; height: 400px; overflow-hidden;'><img src=images/11.jpg</td> 
This is the output, the path and filename are correct

Comment: The value of the src attribute should be quoted. Also, the path to the image is relative to the page you are displaying. Remember it's a URL to the image, not a file path.

Comment: Missing inverted commas?